# Math in email/CMS template variables

Tags: magento-1.7, variables

We have the following two attributes that are used in our transactional emails:

- {{supplier_qty}}
- {{qty}}

We would like to output the result of: `{{supplier_qty * qty}}`

For example, 5 * 1 = 5 (so 5 should be the resulting output).

How can we do this in Magento variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option could be that you add a block to your email template so that you can calculate the items in the block. You can do that by adding the following to your email template:

`{{layout handle="modulename_email_items" supplier={{supplier_qty}} qty={{qty}}}}`

Then in your `layout.xml` file in your theme add the following:

```
<modulename_email_items>
        <block type="core/template" name="items" template="modulename/email/items.phtml"/>
    </modulename_email_items>
```

Then in your template specified above `modulename/email/items.phtml` add the look at calculating it there:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600">        
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <?php if ($supplierQty = $this->getSupplierQty() && $qty = $this->getQty()) : ?>
                 Qty: $supplierQty * $qty
              <?php endif ?>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: interesting approach. +1